# Understanding the compiler errors with std::bind

Tags: c++

How do I get this to compile:

```
#include <functional>
#include <iostream>
#include <memory>
#include <string>

inline void print(std::string string1, std::string* string2)
{
    std::cout << string1 << " " << string2 << std::endl;
    delete string2;
}

class class1
{
    public:
        std::string foo{"Hello"};
        std::shared_ptr<std::string> foo2;
        class1();
};

class1::class1()
{
    auto boundFunc = std::bind(print, foo, std::placeholders::_2);
    foo2 = std::shared_ptr<std::string>(new std::string("world"), boundFunc);
}

int main()
{
    class1 test;
}
```

GCC gives a long and cryptic bunch of error messages:

```
g++ -std=c++17 -o bind bind.cpp 
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.3.1/memory:81,
                 from bind.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Yp*, _Deleter) [with _Yp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:147:48:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Yp*, _Deleter) [with _Yp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
bind.cpp:41:76:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1090:4: error: static assertion failed: deleter expression d(p) is well-formed
    static_assert(__is_invocable<_Deleter&, _Yp*&>::value,
    ^~~~~~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(_Ptr, _Deleter, _Alloc) [with _Ptr = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; _Alloc = std::allocator<void>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:605:57:   required from ‘std::__shared_count<_Lp>::__shared_count(_Ptr, _Deleter) [with _Ptr = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:1088:48:   required from ‘std::__shared_ptr<_Tp, _Lp>::__shared_ptr(_Yp*, _Deleter) [with _Yp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:147:48:   required from ‘std::shared_ptr<_Tp>::shared_ptr(_Yp*, _Deleter) [with _Yp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; <template-parameter-2-3> = void; _Tp = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>]’
bind.cpp:41:76:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:623:11: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>) (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*&)’
        __d(__p); // Call _Deleter on __p.
        ~~~^~~~~
In file included from bind.cpp:19:0:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:547:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:547:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:558:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:558:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:576:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:576:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:588:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:588:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
In file included from /usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr.h:52:0,
                 from /usr/include/c++/7.3.1/memory:81,
                 from bind.cpp:21:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h: In instantiation of ‘void std::_Sp_counted_deleter<_Ptr, _Deleter, _Alloc, _Lp>::_M_dispose() [with _Ptr = std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*; _Deleter = std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>; _Alloc = std::allocator<void>; __gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy _Lp = (__gnu_cxx::_Lock_policy)2]’:
bind.cpp:47:1:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/bits/shared_ptr_base.h:470:25: error: no match for call to ‘(std::_Bind<void (*(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::_Placeholder<2>))(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*)>) (std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*&)’
       { _M_impl._M_del()(_M_impl._M_ptr); }
         ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
In file included from bind.cpp:19:0:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:547:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args)
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:547:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:558:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:558:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:576:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:576:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:588:2: note: candidate: template<class ... _Args, class _Result> _Result std::_Bind<_Functor(_Bound_args ...)>::operator()(_Args&& ...) const volatile [with _Args = {_Args ...}; _Result = _Result; _Functor = void (*)(std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>, std::__cxx11::basic_string<char>*); _Bound_args = {std::__cxx11::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::_Placeholder<2>}]
  operator()(_Args&&... __args) const volatile
  ^~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/7.3.1/functional:588:2: note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
```

I'm not sure what to make of this output, and I haven't found any good documentation of std::bind which provides examples for all the various ways in which it might be used, only the most basic cases.

stackoverflow wants more details, but I don't even know what else to provide. It should be obvious from the code what the problem is. If I knew what to say I would be able to search for it already, but I'm not sure how to describe this problem.

Comment: This sort of crazy is why generally you'll see a recommendation to use lambdas instead of bind if you can avoid it.

Comment: @Megtz happens with everything.. function object usage in templates may result in such mess if that leads to failure of substitution during deduction of arguments. That's why it's essential that programmer should know what they are doing

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple fix: Replace

```
auto boundFunc = std::bind(print, foo, std::placeholders::_2);
```

with

```
auto boundFunc = std::bind(print, foo, std::placeholders::_1);
```

#### Why?

In `std::bind`, the placeholders indicate the index of the argument *to the result function*. `std::placeholders::_1` means "use the first argument passed to me in this position".

When you pass `std::placeholders::_2`, your `boundFunc` will take the wrong number of arguments (2 instead of 1) and no longer be a valid deleter for an `std::shared_ptr`.

Answer (score 2):

The error is subtle but there. You probably used `std::placeholders::_2` because you are using the second argument, right? Well, that's not how you use them.

The number _N designates that the argument number N (when you call the result) is bound to _N. In other words, you need to enumerate them from 1 onwards in your case:

```
auto boundFunc = std::bind(print, foo, std::placeholders::_1);
//                                                         ^
```